# Unable to understand constant train,test split using hashlib

Tags: python, machine-learning

I was doing chapter 1 in "Hands-on Machine Learning in sci-kit learn and Tensor flow"

and I came across code using hashlib which splits test train data from our dataframe.The code is shown below:

```
"""
Creating shuffled testset with constant values in training and updated dataset values going to 
test set in case dataset is updated, this done via hashlib
"""
import hashlib
import numpy as np

def test_set_check(identifier,test_ratio,hash):
    return hash(np.int64(identifier)).digest()[-1]<256*test_ratio
    
def split_train_test(data,test_ratio,id_column,hash=hashlib.md5):
    ids=data[id_column]
    in_test_set=ids.apply(lambda id_:test_set_check(id_,test_ratio,hash))
    return data.loc[~in_test_set],data.loc[in_test_set]
```

I want to understand why:

1. This code `digest()[-1]` gives an integer even though output of .digest() gives us a hashcode
2. Why the output is compared to a constant of 256 in the code < `256*test_ratio`
3. How is it more robust than using `np.random.seed(42)`

I am a newbie to all this so it would be great if you could help me figure this out

Answer (score 1):

1. The [`hashlib.hash.digest`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.hash.digest) method returns a series of bytes. Each byte is a number from 0 to 255. In this particular example, the size of the hashcode is 16, and indexing a particular location in the hashcode returns the value of that particular byte. As the book explains, the author is proposing to use the last byte of the hash as an identifier.
2. The reason that the output is compared to `256 * test_ratio` is because we want to keep only a specific number of samples in our test set that is consistent with `test_ratio`. Since each byte value is between 0 and 255, comparing it to `256 * test_ratio` is essentially setting a "cap" to decide whether or not to keep a sample. For example, if you take the provided housing data and perform the hashing and splitting, you'll notice that you'll end up with a test set of around 4,000 samples which is roughly 20% of the training set. If you're having trouble understanding, imagine we have a list of integers ranging from 0 to 100. Keeping only the integers that are smaller than 100 * 0.2 = 20 will ensure that we end up with 20% of the samples.
3. As the book explains, the entire motivation of going through this rather cumbersome hashing process is to mitigate data snooping bias, which refers to the phenomenon of our model having access to the test set. In order to do so, we want to make sure that we *always* have the same samples in our test set. Simply setting a random seed and then splitting the dataset isn't going to guarantee this, but using hash values will.